# font design cli for readme or logs

Tags: logging, fonts, command-line-interface, readme

I copied and pasted below the cli-designed like font from a log which says **"check"**. May I ask if anyone know if there is an online tool that can convert a defined word into this format?
I suddenly found this interesting to add on our readme md files and also on app loggings

```
     _               _              
 ___| |__   ___  ___| | __
/ __| '_ \ / _ \/ __| |/ / 
| (__| | | |  __/ (__|   <  
\___|_| |_|\___|\___|_|\_
```

Answer (score 0):

found it, this [url](https://www.askapache.com/online-tools/figlet-ascii/) provides a free conversion